# How to monitor JBoss EAP with Prometheus jmx-exporter

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, jmx, jmx-exporter, prometheus-java

I want to monitor some JBoss EAP 7 servers with Prometheus/Grafana (as well as some Wildfly).

I understand I have to use [jmx_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter).

Should I use it as embedded (agent) or side-car (http)?

Which configuration file?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to scrape the metrices using this config

Add the below config to your startup script or standalone.conf

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.3.Final-redhat-1.jar"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/path/to/exporter/jmx_exporter.jar=10001:/path/to/config/config.yaml"
```

Comment: Thank you! After one whole day research this worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use jmx-exporter embedded in the Java JVM virtual machine (use `-javaagent`). That's easier, more robust and gives better insights.

The configuration file depends on the version (JBoss use undertow... that's a different mBeans to collect than JBoss 6).

The jmx-exporter project provides an example configuration file for WildFly 10 [example_configs/wildfly-10.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/example_configs/wildfly-10.yaml).

However, if you use "JBoss EAP for Openshift" containers images, the jmx-exporter agent is already embedded in the containers (set [variables](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform_continuous_delivery/18/html-single/getting_started_with_jboss_eap_for_openshift_container_platform/index): `AB_PROMETHEUS_ENABLE=true` and sometimes this one too `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND=-Dwildfly.statistics-enabled=true`)

If you don't use Red Hat's container images, you can still use the ssame jmx-exporter configuration files. Those files (jmx-exporter-config.yaml) are open-source and available on github:

- on master branch [JBoss 7.3](https://github.com/jboss-container-images/jboss-eap-modules/tree/7.3.x/jboss/container/eap/prometheus/jmx-exporter-config/artifacts/opt/jboss/container/prometheus/etc)
- on older branches [JBoss 6.4 (and 7.1 and 7.2)](https://github.com/jboss-container-images/jboss-eap-modules/tree/6.4.x/jboss/container/eap/prometheus/config)

Comment: We are trying to install jmx_exporter for JBoss7.3 in domain mode, but it fails with the following error

[Server:server-two] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wildfly/common/net/HostName
[Server:server-two]     at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord.<init>

Comment: @NageswaraRao here is a blog post explaining how to setup jmx-exporter for WF in domain mode. Maybe it helps:  [WF domain mode](https://lazarbulic.com/blog/2018/05/25/prometheus-jmx_exporter-for-jboss-wildfly/)